# Can I have a NEMA 14-30 outlet on a 50 amp breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I'm having an electrician install a new circuit in my garage. I don't currently have a Tesla or other high powered car, but I might in the future, so I want to have the wiring capable of handling a NEMA 14-50 plug, so presumably 6/4-guage wiring.

However, currently I only need to have a 240v 30amp plug for some equipment, so I'm planning to have NEMA 14-30 plugs installed at the end. Is this allowed to be installed on a 50-amp breaker circuit?

I know that regular 120v 20-amp breakers are allowed to have 15-amp outlets installed. But I don't know if a NEMA 14-30 plug can be installed on a 50-amp circuit.

Alternatively, could I have a 30-amp breaker installed and then later upgrade it to a 50 amp breaker and a NEMA 14-50 plug myself without requiring any new inspections or permits?

Comment: Inspection and permit requirements are determined by state and city ordinance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Fit a 30A breaker for a 30A socket.

The 20A/15A exception *is an exception* based on UL requirements for 15A sockets, and it does not apply to anything else.